# Fire button event manually

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a search text box on my WPF Windows. Whenever, the user presses enter key after writing some query in the textBox, the process should start.

Now, I also have this Search button, in the event of which I perform all this process.

So, for a texBox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Text="Query here" FontSize="20" Padding="5" Width="580" KeyDown="textBox1_KeyDown"></TextBox>

private void queryText_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Return)
            {
                //how do I fire the button event from here?
            }
        }
```

Comment: see this post http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/03/09/how-to-programmatically-click-a-button/ or this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7551766/273200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but rather move your search logic into a method such as `DoSearch` and call it from both locations (text box and the search button).

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you also mention about the other method?

Comment: Call the event handler directly.  For example: `btnSearch_onClick(this, null);`

Comment: @PhilipFourie: That won't do as the event args are being used.

Comment: @H.B. I don't think that is the case. OP wants to call the search button's event which implemtation is not provided.  Cannot tell if the search button event is using the args.

Comment: @PhilipFourie: Oh, you are right, sorry about that, then let's say it *might* be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about manually invoking `buttonSearch_onClick(this, null);`?

Answer (score 0):

You can Create a Common Method to do search for ex

```
public void MySearch()
{
     //Logic
}
```

Then Call it for diffetnt places you want like...

```
private void queryText_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
     {
         if (e.Key == Key.Return)
         {
                      MySearch();
         }
     }

private void buttonSearch_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MySearch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A event can not be fired/raised from outside the class in which it is defined.(Using reflection you can definitely do that, but not a good practice.)

Having said that, you can always call the button click event handler from the code as simple method call like below

```
private void queryText_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        OnSearchButtonClick(SearchButton, null);
    }
}
```